# Default php.ini file and changes

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I am currently using HOSTFORWEB as my hosting company. I want to make some changes to the php.ini file but i cannot find it (the path displayed by phpinfo() is nowhere to be found).

Reading similar questions to mine, i understood that its not possible for the hosting company to let each user alter their default php.ini file. Also i read that its possible for me to build my php.ini (or php5.ini for PHP 5) file and upload it to root folder.

My question is: Is there a default php.ini (or php5.ini) file that suits all servers with the proper customization? Is the file in the link below what i am searching for?

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/php.ini-production

If it is, what are the parameters i have to change in order to work on the HOSTFORWEB web server?

Also, to apply this php.ini file to my entire website i have to change the .htaccess file somehow. Is there a default code for this as well? Because i see different solutions for the same question:

---

"If you would like to load your local php.ini file recursively for all your subfolders, you just need to add the following line to your .htaccess file inside the folder where you would like to apply the recursion:

Code:
SuPHP_ConfigPath /home/username/public_html/php.ini

### The above assumes that you are going to replace "username" with your actual cpanel username and that your php.ini file lives inside of public_html."

and

---

"You can create custom php.ini files for each directory in your web site, but many people configure settings in one php.ini file and then apply it to the entire web site. To do this, add the following line to the .htaccess file in your web site's document root directory. Replace USERNAME with your A2 Hosting username:

### SetEnv PHPRC /home/USERNAME/public_html/php.ini"

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Usually webhosting companies don't give access to modify php.ini unless it is a VPS or dedicated server. If it is, then try looking in `/etc/php` or something similar

Comment: I am not sure, but i suppose there must be a way to bypass the php.ini of the hosting company and use your own. For example if i want to alter session.name from PHPSESSID to CUSTOMSESSID..

Comment: Usually you create your own php.ini in shared hosting websites... If the admin allows, it will override the original one.

Comment: Now i am reading that i could make the changes through .htaccess file without creating my own php.ini file. I hope this is correct.